# Variable as Difference of 2 Variables

Tags: variable-definitions, algebra

I would like to evaluate a function based on the absolute difference of two variables. An example:

```
g=5*x-5*x*y-5*y
diff=x-y
D[g,x]
D[g,y]
D[g,diff]
```

I cannot find an alternative definition for "diff" that avoids the error message "General::ivar: "x-y is not a valid variable."

Thank you!

Comment: How can you differentiate with respect to difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ClearAll[g, x, y, diff];
g = 5*x - 5*x*y - 5*y;
```

Maybe:

```
D[g /. x -> (diff + y), diff]
(* 5 - 5 y *)
```

or

```
D[g /. y -> (x - diff), diff]
(* 5 + 5 x *)
```